# Using map function to present the array of objects with bootstrap cards

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks, map-function

I'm trying to present the movie API array data in bootstrap cards but it seems that I still don't understand something about react hooks or map functions because I can't get the code right. I get this "TypeError: setTrendingResults.map is not a function" .

My code:

```
import Hero from "./Hero";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const TrendingCard = ({ trending }) => {
  const trendPosterUrl = `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${trending.poster_path}`;
  const trendDetailUrl = `/movies/${trending.id}`;

  return (
    <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-2">
      <div className="card">
        <img
          src={trendPosterUrl}
          class="card-img-top"
          alt={trending.original_title}
        />
        <div className="card-body">
          <h5 className="card-title">{trending.original_title}</h5>
          <Link to={trendDetailUrl} class="btn btn-primary">
            Show details
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const TrendingView = (data) => {
  const [trendingResults, setTrendingResults] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/movie/week?api_key=776d38251dae661e04c01631cfa95286"
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setTrendingResults(data.results);
      });
  });

  const trendingHtml = setTrendingResults.map((obj, i) => {
    return <TrendingCard trending={obj} key={i} />;
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <Hero text="Trending" />
      {trendingHtml && (
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">{trendingHtml}</div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default TrendingView;
```

Comment: remove space after useState

Comment: `setTrendingResults.map(...)` ----> `trendingResults.map(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use valid state for mapping a card. `trendingResults` insted of `setTrendingResults`.

Here I convert a trendingHtml with `React.useMemo` which helps to avoid re-render-related stuff.

```
const TrendingView = (data) => {
  const [trendingResults, setTrendingResults] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/movie/week?api_key=776d38251dae661e04c01631cfa95286"
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setTrendingResults(data.results);
      });
  });


  const trendingHtml = React.useMemo(()=> trendingResults?.map((obj, i) => {
    return (<TrendingCard trending={obj} key={i} />)
  }),[trendingResults])

  return (
    <div>
      <Hero text="Trending" />
      {trendingHtml && (
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">{trendingHtml}</div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default TrendingView;
```

Answer (score 0):

***setTrendingResults*** is used to set the value to ***trendingResults*** state. You have to use ***trendingResults*** instead of ***setTrendingResults***.

```
const trendingHtml = trendingResults.map((obj, i) => {
  return <TrendingCard trending={obj} key={i} />
})
```